# Get the parameter value from a Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have the following class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool Delete(Product product)
    {
        // some code.
    }
}
```

Now I have a helper class that looks like this

```
public class Helper<T, TResult>
{

    public Type Type;
    public string Method;
    public Type[] ArgTypes;
    public object[] ArgValues;

    public Helper(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var body = (System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;

        this.Type = typeof(T);
        this.Method = body.Method.Name;
        this.ArgTypes = body.Arguments.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray();
        this.ArgValues = ???
    }
}
```

The idea ist to use this code from somewhere:

```
// I am returning a helper somewhere
public Helper<T> GetMethod<T>()
{
    var product = GetProduct(1);
    return new Helper<MyClass>(x => x.Delete(product));
}

// some other class decides, when to execute the helper 
// Invoker already exists and is responsible for executing the method
// that is the main reason I don't just comile and execute my Expression
public bool ExecuteMethod<T>(Helper<T> helper)
{
    var instance = new MyClass();
    var Invoker = new Invoker(helper.Type, helper.Method, helper.ArgTypes, helper.ArgValues);
    return (bool)Invoker.Invoke(instance);
}
```

The point where I am stuck is how to extract the arguments from the expression itself.

I found this way

```
((ConstantExpression)((MemberExpression)body.Arguments[0]).Expression).Value
```

which seems to be an object type with a field "product" but I believe there must be a simpler solution.

Any suggestions.

**Update**

Just to clarify, I modified my code according to what I want to achive. In my real word application I already have a class that does the same but without an expression tree:

```
var helper = new Helper(typeof(MyClass), "Delete", 
    new Type[] { typeof(Product) }, new object[] {product}));
```

The main reason for my `Helper<T>` is to have Compile-Time checking if the method signature is valid.

**Update 2**

This is my current implementation, is there a better way to acces the values, without using reflection?

```
public Helper(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
{
    var body = (System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;

    this.Type = typeof(T);
    this.Method = body.Method.Name;
    this.ArgTypes = body.Arguments.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray();

    var values = new List<object>();
    foreach(var arg in body.Arguments)
    {
        values.Add(
            (((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value).GetType()
                .GetField(exp.Member.Name)
                .GetValue(((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value);
        );
    }
    this.ArgValues = values.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: is there any reason you can't just compile the expression and execute it? Or is this just messing around to learn expression trees?

Comment: @rbev +1 beat me to it.

Comment: Heck, why not just directly invoke `Delete(product)`?

Comment: @Aron, this is just an example, helper will be instanced and passed around.

Comment: @rbev: He wouldn't even need an expression. A simply delegate would suffice. The OP needs to clarify his constraints before this can be answered

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I didn't want to go overboard with the suggestions, he seems to be really keen on expression trees!

Comment: You want to pass a Delegate about NOT an Expression.

Comment: @Aron, No I really want the Expression. Otherwise tell me more about how to extract `a) The declaring type`, `b) the methods name`, `c) the Arguments Count / Type / Values` from a Delegate

Comment: There is no easy way to do this...the clue should be in the huge number of direct casts you are using. There is no guarantee that the body is a method call expression. Also it is possible that the Arguments to the method call expression could be composite expression...for example another method call. But if you are looking for all the ConstantExpressions, you could ExpressionVisitor...again...what is your use case?

Comment: Use case is to have compile time checking: `new Helper<MyClass>(x => x.Delete(product));` is currently implemented in a non generic fashion: `new Helper(typeof(MyClass), "Delete", 
    new Type[] { typeof(Product) }, new object[] {product}));` which has the risk that I can rename the Delete() method or simply change the argument count without getting a compile time error.

Comment: But how is that information used on the otherside? You are generating lots of information in the Helper class...but how is Helper used? Why can't you just use Delegates? Why do you NEED expressions? What is the Problem domain that Helper is trying to solve. Assume Helper does not exist.

Comment: Assuming you really want to use `Invoker`, can't you modify it to work with lambdas too?

Comment: If it is JUST trying to use invoke. You can just use compile. But the method name isn't used... I don't understand why you need the arguments and the method.

Comment: The point is, you don't have to understand. The big picture is to complex and unnecessary for this question. The main question was not `How to refactor xyz?` but `How to achive xyz?` If it is not possible to improve or you don't have an answer, thats ok to. But saying, you don't understand it, so it must be wrong, is not helping.

Comment: This implementation is the most comprehensive I've found: https://github.com/dotFramework/dynamic-query/blob/77f4a8546c2048f824135013b4e3e464586c3ff1/source/Src/DynamicQuery/Helpers/ExpressionHelper.cs#L64

Comment: @Arithmomaniac thanks ; already solved it but this might become handy in the future.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This method works pretty well. It returns the argument types and values for an Expression>

```
    private static KeyValuePair<Type, object>[] ResolveArgs<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var body = (System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<Type, object>>();

        foreach (var argument in body.Arguments)
        {
            var exp = ResolveMemberExpression(argument);
            var type = argument.Type;

            var value = GetValue(exp);

            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, object>(type, value));
        }

        return values.ToArray();
    }

    public static MemberExpression ResolveMemberExpression(Expression expression)
    {

        if (expression is MemberExpression)
        {
            return (MemberExpression)expression;
        }
        else if (expression is UnaryExpression)
        {
            // if casting is involved, Expression is not x => x.FieldName but x => Convert(x.Fieldname)
            return (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(expression.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static object GetValue(MemberExpression exp)
    {
        // expression is ConstantExpression or FieldExpression
        if (exp.Expression is ConstantExpression)
        {
            return (((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value)
                    .GetType()
                    .GetField(exp.Member.Name)
                    .GetValue(((ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value);    
        }
        else if (exp.Expression is MemberExpression)
        {
            return GetValue((MemberExpression)exp.Expression);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant (added a missing type argument):

`KeyValuePair<Type, object>[] ResolveArgs<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)`

Comment: @PatrickKoorevaar You're right. In my code the method is inside a generic class with the type argument, so I missed that part.

Comment: I think I'm showing my ignorance here. Why do you need to call `GetType().GetField([name]).GetValue(constantExp.Value)` on the result of `constantExpression.Value` ? Is it that the `.Value` property of a `var v = 1;` expression is not the **1** being assigned? Is the literal **1** value in a field on the object representation of the expression returned by `constantExpression.Value`?

Comment: It's been a while, but if I remember correctly, the expression `x => x.Delete(product)` is represented by an object which I get from `(ConstantExpression)exp.Expression).Value` and this object has a field with the same name as `exp.Member.Name` which holds the `product` instance I want to retrieve. The method name `GetValue` is a bit misleading, `GetExpressionArgumentValue` would be better.

Answer (score 17):

You can compile the argument expression and then invoke it to calculate the value:

```
var values = new List<object>();
foreach(var arg in body.Arguments)
{
    var value = Expression.Lambda(argument).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
    values.Add(value);
}
this.ArgValues = values.ToArray();
```

Comment: arguments should be arg as declared in foreach.

Comment: In [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/03/11/how-can-i-get-objects-and-property-values-from-expression-trees/) artice mentioned that compile isn't fast operation.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of creation of a delegate using a lambda. The object instance is encapsulated into the delegate using a C# feature called closure.

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    //This following line cannot be changed to var declaration 
    //since C# can't infer the type.
Func<Product, bool> deleteDelegate = p => instance.Delete(p);
Product product = new Product();
bool deleted = deleteDelegate(product);
```

Alternatively you are trying to create a Helper that automagically Currys.

```
public class Helper<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> methodLambda)
    {
        var instance = new T();
        return methodLamda(instance);
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    var helper = new Helper<MyClass>();
    var product = new Product();
    helper.Execute(x => x.Delete(product));
}
```

However I have to say this problem looks suspiciously like the creation of a Helper class to handle the lifetime of a WCF proxy....You know...just say...in which case this ISN'T how I would approach this...simply because this approach leaks WCF specific code into your domain.

Comment: That is totally not what I wan't.