# Get the value of params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] exps as where condition and also get the name of properties and assigned values to them

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, func

1- How can I get the value of `exps` in `Find` method same as where condition in SQL? like: `(WHERE City='CCC' and Name='NNN')`

2- How can I get assigned value at `exps` in `Find` method ("CCC", "NNN")?

3- How can I get the parameter names? (City, Name)

```
var instantRep = new BaseRepository<Address>();
instantRep.Find( p1 => p1.City == "CCC" && p1.Name == "NNN");
```

**Find Method:**

```
public class BaseRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public void Find(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] exps)
    {
        // Get the values of exps as where condition?
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> x in exps)
        {
            // Get the property name? (City, Name)
            // get the right value? ("CCC", "NNN")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the parameter value from a Linq Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651835/get-the-parameter-value-from-a-linq-expression)

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Sounds like you are asking multiple wrong questions in some sort of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)